# Playig video content (mp4) on iOS device

Tags: objective-c, ios

we have some commercial videos hosted on a server that are in mp4 format. What iOS class can we use/research to play them? Any additional tips would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A movie player (of type MPMoviePlayerController) manages the playback
>   of a movie from a file or a network stream. Playback occurs in a view
>   owned by the movie player and takes place either fullscreen or inline.
>   You can incorporate a movie player’s view into a view hierarchy owned
>   by your app, or use an MPMoviePlayerViewController object to manage
>   the presentation for you.